# sent hex code via python serial to printer

Tags: python, serial-port

I need to sent ESCPOS commands to my thermal printer.
The commands are listed here:
http://pyramidacceptors.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ESC_POS_Protocol_Commands_REV_B.pdf

How can I sent easy HEX code via python serial?
Serial connection is done.
I want to do a fullcut and tried:

```
content = "\x1B\x6D"
ser.write(content)
```

But it doesn't work, I will need to use the .pdf often, so is there anything to be careful of when using hex in python?
For example, print and feed paper n lines commands should be in python:
1B 64 n
n = lines

```
content = "\x1B\x64\x5"
ser.write(content)
```

Comment: There is already a python module for doing that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-escpos

Comment: doesn't work on my raspberry pi, on windows the lib is buggy, pictures don't work.

Comment: I made this library in Python https://github.com/benoitguigal/python-epson-printer. It is inspired from python-escpos but with better image printing and a slightly different API. You may find it useful

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I tried ESCPOS from google before, seems like my printer (phoenix thermal) have some problems by connection via USB. I tried VID and PID so often, but always the backend doesn't seems to work. I made the connection via python-serial, this works fine. I will take a look into your image printing, because this makes some problems, printing images lager then 128*128 results in not readable images on the printed ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not send "hex". You send binary data -- that is a stream of *bytes*.

Each *byte* might be *represented* (among others) as an hexadecimal number from `00` to `FF` or as an ASCII character.

As far as I understand, the doc describing the ESC POS protocol gives the "human representation" of the various command that should be send as binary.

As an example, given the *"print and feed"*, I read:

> ```
>                                     HEX        ASCII
>  Print and feed paper n lines     1B 64 n     Esc d n
> ```

That means, in order to "print and feed *5* lines", you have to send *3 bytes*:

```
\x1B\x64\x05
```

In Python >= 2.6, this is written (notice the `b` prefix):

```
b"\x1B\x64\x05"
```

Or given your code fragment, that leads to:

```
content = b"\x1B\x64\x05"
ser.write(content)
```

Please note I don't know that device. Maybe you have to send some kind of prefix to switch it into "command mode". Maybe not.